# Getting a list of all guild members and banning them in discord.js using node.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Just like the title explains I am trying to get a list of all the users loop through the list of user ID's and ban them all. When i try to do a Member[i].ban; it prints an error saying ban is not a function. Any ideas on how to go about this?

My code (EDITED)

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const token = 'HIDDEN';

bot.on('ready', () => {
    const Guild = bot.guilds.cache.get("HIDDEN")
    const Members = Guild.members.cache.map(member => member.id);
    //console.log(Members);
    for (i = 0; i < Members.length; i++) {
        Guild.members.cache.map(member => member.ban());
      }

})

bot.login(token);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to check if the member you are trying to ban, can actually be banned. When you loop through the members of a guild, the guild owner is included. The bot cannot ban the guild owner and therefore it will throw an error.

---

```js
Guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
    if (member.bannable) member.ban();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Guild.members.cache.map(member => member.ban());
```

Comment: Thanks! One step further, however i get this error (node:18728) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions. I did put the bot above everyones roles and gave it the permission to ban people but it still throws that error